# Laravel - Recursive Category System

Tags: recursion, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to write a global fn for my cat system that is in the base controller.
here is the fn inside the base cont

```
public function rec_cat($table,$col,$col_id,$rec_arr=array()) {
  $ups=DB::table($table)->where($col,$col_id)->get();
  foreach ($ups as $up) {
    $rec_arr[]=$up;
    $this->rec_cat($table,$col,$col_id,$rec_arr);
  }
  return $rec_arr;
}
```

when I try to call this fn in my controller

```
$select=$this->rec_cat('kategori','up_id','0');
return var_dump($select);
```

I get this error

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 196605 bytes)
```

The bytes written in the error is smaller than the allowed memory size so I think I have another problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have an infinite loop in your function, it just keeps calling itself over and over again until you run out of memory. I cant tell what you are trying to do, but you are just calling the *same* function with the *same* variables each time. You need to be supplying new variables on each recursive call...

Comment: Can you explain what you think this function is *supposed* to do?

Comment: Of course it has an infinite loop. Forgive me for my noobness :) The subject can be locked.

Comment: I have put my comment as an answer so you can accept it (and thus the question appeared marked and closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your function, it just keeps calling itself over and over again until you run out of memory.

I cant tell what you are trying to do, but you are just calling the same function with the same variables each time.

You need to be supplying new variables on each recursive call..